# Resolve Undefined namespace Mailer CakePHP 3.0.3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to create a **Email** Reusable provided by CakePHP 3 but even the the following documentation but got the following error:

```
use Cake\Mailer\Mailer;
```

**Error:**

> Undefined namespace Mailer
>
> Referenced namespace is not found.

I created the file in the same directory specified in the documentation

**NOTE:** I am using **CakePHP 3.0.3**

[Link to the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/email.html#creating-reusable-emails)

Comment: There are two version here that need to be considered, the one of the app template (current 3.0.4), and the one of the CakePHP core (`vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`, current 3.0.11)! Please always mention at least the one of the core, and ideally the one of the app template too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mailers are only available as of CakePHP 3.1, which is currently in beta phase. Maybe the docs were updated a little too early.

- **http://bakery.cakephp.org/2015/08/01/cakephp_3_1_0_beta_released.html**
- **http://bakery.cakephp.org/2015/08/05/cakephp_3_0_11_and_3_1_0_beta2_released.html**
- **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tree/3.1**